# Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times With Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am getting an error

> *Invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times*

and below is the my code structure

```
public class GenerateAddress : IGenerateAddress 
{
    public GenerateAddress(IAddress createAdd, IValidate validate) {
       //constructor 
    }

    public Address GetAddressFromA(string name){..}
}

public class SaveAddress : ISaveAddress 
{
    public SaveAddress(IGenerateAddress generateaddress) {
        //constructor 
    }

    public bool Save(string name)
    {
        var address = generateaddress.GetAddressFromA(name);
        ......
        //Rest of the code to save 
    }
}
```

Test Method to Test Class SaveAddress

```
public void TestVerifyGetAddressIsCalled()
{
    var mockIAddress = new Mock<IAddress>();
    var mockValidate = new Mock<IValidate>();

    var genAddress = new Mock<IGenerateAddress>();

    var objGenAdress = new GenerateAddress(mockIAddress.Object, mockValidate.Object) // 

    var objSaveAddress = new SaveAddress(objGenAdress);

    objSaveAddress.Save("dddd");

    //Verify if IGenerateAddress 'GenerateAddress' is called

    genAddress.Verify(a=>a.GenerateAddress("ddddd"),Times.Once); // Throws Excepted Invocation 
}
```

I need to verify if `GenerateAddress` is called or not. I also did `Setup` and assigned values to *`Address`* object but even those values are not been set .. Not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: you never pass `genAddress` to `SaveAddress` indirectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an `IGenerateAddress` you created manually (`objGenAdress`) with `SaveAddress` instead of the mocked `genAddress`.

Also given that the SUT is the `SaveAddress` which only needed the `IGenerateAddress`, there is no need for the other mocks.

```
public void TestVerifyGetAddressIsCalled() { 
    //Arrange
    var genAddress = new Mock<IGenerateAddress>();

    var objSaveAddress = new SaveAddress(genAddress.Object);

    var name = "dddd";

    //Act
    objSaveAddress.Save(name);

    //Assert
    //Verify if 'IGenerateAddress.GenerateAddress' is called    
    genAddress.Verify(a => a.GenerateAddress(name), Times.Once);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're calling `Save` with 'dddd' (4 d's), but verifying it was called with 'ddddd' (5 d's).

It's safer to put the real data in a variable and reference it in both cases:

```
var name = "dddd";
objSaveAddress.Save(name);

genAddress.Verify(a=>a.GenerateAddress(name),Times.Once);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think after selected reply, if we refactor code First create SaveAddress class as mock and passing parameter genAddress with CallBase property set as true. Default value of this property is false. if you don't use this parameter your method call returns null and you get this.post title error.

```
        var genAddress = new Mock<IGenerateAddress>();

        var objSaveAddress = new Mock<SaveAddress>(genAddress.Object){CallBase = true};

        var name = "dddd";

        //Act
        objSaveAddress.Object.Save(name);

        //Assert
        //Verify if IGenerateAddress 'GenerateAddress' is called    
        genAddress.Verify(a => a.GetAddressFromA(name), Times.Once);
```